# Connection refused in multi-server TCP socket connection with Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, network-programming, distributed-system

I have 3 servers I would like to link so that they communicate between each other. The goal is to run MapReduce in a distributed way.

I have a problem when proceeding to a multi-server connection using TCP socket in python.
I simplified the code so that it enhances the understanding of this particular problem.

IMPORTANT INFO : This exact code is sent and ran on every server of the list "computers" using the bash code given at the very bottom of this thread.

`

```
from _thread import *
import socket
from time import sleep

computers = ["137.194.142.130", "137.194.142.131", "137.194.142.133"]
list_PORT = [3652,4457, 6735, 9725]
idt = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
SIZE = 1024
FORMAT = "utf-8"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((idt, list_PORT[computers.index(idt)+1]))
server.listen() 

sleep(4)        #So that every server have time to listen before 
                # the other ones start to connect with the next part of the code 

list_socket_rec = []
if computers.index(idt) != 0:
    for server in computers[:computers.index(idt)]:
        socket_nb = 0
        skt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        list_socket_rec.append(skt)
        list_socket_rec[socket_nb].connect((server, list_PORT[computers.index(idt)]))  # error connection refused
        socket_nb += 1

        #In this loop, I'm trying to connect to every server whose index are "smaller" in the computers list (in order to not have duplicates)
```

The error that I get is the following: (occuring on the connect() function at the end of the code)
`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file", line 24, in <module>
    list_socket_rec[socket_nb].connect((server, list_PORT[computers.index(idt)]))  # fonctionne pas ==> connection refused
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Does someone know how to solve this error please?

Shell code to run the servers :
`

```
#!/bin/bash
# A simple variable example
login="login"
remoteFolder="/tmp/$login/"
fileName="server"
fileExtension=".py"
computers=("137.194.142.130", "137.194.142.131", "137.194.142.133")

for c in ${computers[@]}; do
  command0=("ssh" "$login@$c" "lsof -ti | xargs kill -9")
  command1=("ssh" "$login@$c" "rm -rf $remoteFolder;mkdir $remoteFolder")
  command2=("scp" "$fileName$fileExtension" "$login@$c:$remoteFolder$fileName$fileExtension")
  command3=("ssh" "$login@$c" "cd $remoteFolder; python3 $fileName$fileExtension")
  echo ${command0[*]}
  "${command0[@]}"
  echo ${command1[*]}
  "${command1[@]}"
  echo ${command2[*]}
  "${command2[@]}"
  echo ${command3[*]}
  "${command3[@]}" &
done
```

`

I've tried to bind/connect on different port for each connection because I thought the problem could come from multipole connection on the same port but the error was still there.

I have tried to go manually on 2 of the servers, I ran the previous code on the first of the computers list and then on the second of the computers list, and the connection worked.

Comment: Connection refused means that the server is not listening in the first place or that a firewall in between client and server (maybe on client, maybe on server, maybe in between) blocks connections. Thus make sure that a) the server is running in the first place b) it is listing on the expected port(s), c) the packets from the client arrive at the server side (not blocked)